# How to access private set properties in derived class

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have a simple inheritance situation as follows:

I expected to be able to set the properties in Class2 from Class1 but this is not the case. Is there a way to set access to the properties in Class 2 so they act like protected variables?

```
public abstract class Class2
{
    public DateTime Added { get; private set; }
    public int ID { get; private set; }
}

public class Class1 : Class2
{
    public string ImageFilename { get; set; }
    public string LinkText { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried making the set protected?

Comment: [protected](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcd5672a.aspx)

Comment: Please define _"act like protected variables"_, as that can mean a lot. Do you want the properties to not be accessible from outside `Class2` and its inheritance chain? Do you want the property to be publicly gettable, but protected settable? And so on. And please share your research.

Comment: `"so they act like protected variables"` - I don't understand... If you know what `protected` is, why aren't you using it?  Is there more to this problem that you're not explaining?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set them as `protected`, not `private`. This lets you access it from derived classes, but not external classes.

```
public abstract class Class2
{
    protected DateTime Added { get; set; }
    protected int ID { get; set; }
}

public class Class1 : Class2
{
    public string ImageFilename { get; set; }
    public string LinkText { get; set; }

    public Class1()
    {
        //You can set the variables from inside Class 1.
        base.Added = DateTime.Now();
        base.ID = 1;
    }
}
```

If you want the properties to still be exposed externally, but as readonly, you can set the individual setters are protected instead:

```
public abstract class Class2
{
    public DateTime Added { get; protected set; }
    public int ID { get; protected set; }
}
```

Comment: Ah, you learn something every day - well you do as a noob!

Comment: But your example code still has them as `private`.

Comment: Your setters are still private.  All you've done is reduce the visibility of public members, which is a breaking change.

Comment: This will make the getter protected but the setter private.

Comment: Sorry, i'd missed the private set. I've updated it accordingly